# Зачем нужен ReactJS если есть EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ejs

Мой вопрос может показаться простым, но всё же спросить не у кого. Я недавно открыл для себя шаблонизатор ejs и от него просто в восторге, на нём можно спокойно создавать динамические страницы любой сложности, и в связи с этим вопрос, а зачем нам нужен react js, если есть ejs?? Реакт позволяет создавать сайты одностранички с огромным функционалом с рендорингом, что упрощает(или нет) seo-оптимизацию, есть ещё какие нибудь преимущества у Реакта над ejs?

Пробовал искать ответы в интернете, но таких вопросов никто не задаёт...

Comment: Филосовский вопрос. Это как "Почему покупают фолькваген если есть опель?". Более правильным, наверное, будет размещение этого вопроса [на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) для обсуждения. Мое мнение, что это вопрос удобства и скорости разработки.

Comment: Вопрос из разряда зачем нужен экскаватор, если если есть лопата? С помощью шаблонизаторов действительно можно (и возможно более рационально) создавать небольшие приложения или их компоненты. Однако при создании приложения с действительно большим функционалом, ваш код очень быстро перестанет быть сколько то ни было читаемым и поддерживаемым. Тем более используя шаблонизатор, вы потратите огромное количество времени на то, что React (или Vue или ...) делает за вас по умолчанию.